# PHP5　PEAR MDB2_Common::freeResult()関数の｢Call to undefined function｣エラー

Tags: php

■Webサーバー移転の為、次のようにOS/PHP等が変更・Version-Upになりました。
　サーバーOS：FreeBSD4.7-RELEASE-p11 → Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4
　Apache：1.3.42 → 2.0.64
　PHP：4.4.7 → 5.3.28
　PEAR：1.5.4 → 1.9.4
　MySQL：4.1.21 → 5.5.35

■この移転作業後、今迄問題のなかったMDB2_Common::freeResult() 関数（DBレコードを
　Getした結果セットを削除し、結果セットが使用していたメモリを開放する関数）で、
　トラブっています。
　$○○->freeResult($△△);」を実行すると、下記エラーメッセージが画面に表示されて
　止まってしまいます。
【エラーメッセージ】Fatal error: Call to undefined function: 
　　　　　　　　　　MDB2_Driver_mysql::freeResult(). 
　　　　　　　　　　in /usr/local/php5.3/lib/php/MDB2.php on line 1936

尚、$○○は該当DBオブジェクトのアドレス。$△△は、PEARのgetAllメソッドで取得したデータ
　が入っている配列変数。
　MDB2.phpは、親プログラムの中で｢require_once( "MDB2.php" );｣しています。

このトラブルを解決する方法を、御教え下さい。

Comment: MDB2のバージョンはいくつでしょうか

Comment: MDB2.phpの46行目に「// $Id: MDB2.php,v 1.292 2007/04/25 09:31:01 quipo Exp $」とありますので、バージョンは1.292ではないかと思われます。

Comment: 返事が遅くなり、申し訳ありませんでした。flied onion様の御回答、大変役に立ちました。有難う御座いました。

Answer (score 1):

[こっち(qa@it)](http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9847)で回答しましたけど反応がないので。MDBではfreeResultな様ですが、MDB2ならfreeなのではないでしょうか。

https://pear.php.net/package/MDB/docs/1.3.0/MDB/MDB_Common.html#methodfreeResult

https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Result_Common.html#methodfree

1.292というのはcvsのリビジョンだと思うのでバージョンではないと思います（MDB2のバージョンは2.0.0からかと）

[いろいろなところ](http://www.phppro.jp/qa/4714)で質問しているようですが、マルチポストするならきちんと全部対応してもらえますか？